# Javascript - Find out if date is between two dates, ignoring year

Tags: javascript

I need to find out if my date is between two dates (for checking birthday whether its between +/- 10 days of current date) without taking care of year (because for birthday we don't need year).

I have tried the following but its typical match and will not ignore year. If i ll compare only date and month then overlap on month end makes problems.

```
(moment(new Date()).isBetween(moment(date).add(10, 'days'), moment(date).subtract(10, 'days')));
```

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: I have tried the same as @Jonas W. mentioned in his answer or more specifically i have tried 
(moment(new Date()).isBetween(moment(date).add(10, 'days'), moment(date).subtract(10, 'days')))

Comment: You must insert codes you tried in question in good format and put your problems and issues.

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee you are right. i don't know how i missed them. I think now its reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that i was end up with.

```
const birthDate= new Date(birthDate);
      birthDate.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear());
const isBirthdayAround = Math.abs(birthday - new Date) < 10*24*60*60*1000;
```

And if you are using moment then:

```
const birthDate= new Date(birthDate);
      birthDate.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear());
const isBirthdayAround = moment(new Date()).isBetween(moment(birthDate).subtract(10, 'days'), moment(birthDate).add(10, 'days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Math.abs(birthday - new Date) < 10/*d*/ * 24/*h*/ * 60/*min*/ * 60/*secs*/ * 1000/*ms*/)
  alert("somewhat in the range");
```

You can just work with dates as if they were milliseconds. Just get the difference by subtracting them, then check if its smaller than 10 days in milliseconds.

Comment: The problem is there with birthday year. For example if birthday="05/25/1993" then difference will be huge. We have to skip year and see if its birthday within 10 days or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) with methods [subtract](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) and [add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) to find any date you want.

Example:

- > moment().add(7, 'days'); // next 7 days
- > moment().subtract(7, 'days'); // 7 days ago

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you.

```js
var birthDate = new Date("05/16/1993");
var day = birthDate.getDate();
var month = birthDate.getMonth();
var currentDate = new Date();
var tempDate = new Date();
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 

var dayDifference = 10 // you can set here difference

tempDate = new Date(tempDate.setMonth(month,day))
var timeDiff = tempDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
timeDiff = Math.round(timeDiff / oneDay)

if(-dayDifference <= timeDiff && timeDiff <=dayDifference){
  alert("matched")
}
else{
  alert("not matched")
}
```